# Webdriver, WebElement. How to get a element with fieldid

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have this element to catch:

```
<li id="GridLayout_route.organization" class="popupCustomizeColumnsItems isFrozen" fieldid="11151"/>
<div class="columnItem">Organization</div>
```

It's in a list of elements but I want to catch this item from a list.
Ii want to catch by `fieldid="11151"`, I tried with xpath and it didn't work. The xpath changes with the order list are different.

I tried with ccsSelector like this:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li .popupCustomizeColumnsItems [fieldid=11029]"));
```

Actually I tried many ways but none successful so far.

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: Post the ways you tried but did not work. Especially the XPath.

Comment: @SiKing he isn't using xpath, he's using CSS. `:)`

Comment: @sircapsalot Read the OP again: "I tried with xpath and it didn't work."

Comment: ah yep.  missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Your spaces are your problem.

Change

```
"li .popupCustomizeColumnsItems [fieldid=11029]"
```

to

```
"li.popupCustomizeColumnsItems[fieldid='11029']
```

With the spaces, this means (in English):

> Find me an `<li>` element, then under that `<li>`, find me anything that has the class `popupCustomizeColumnsItems`, then following that, anything that has the attribute `fieldid` that `equals` `11029`.

This means (in CSS):

```
li *[class~='popupCustomizeColumnsItems'] *[fieldid=11029]
```